# Concerning the Connectedness of Certain Unitaries in the Stabilization $\mathcal{K}A$ of a C$^{*}$-algebra $A$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I am working through Rordam's book on $K$-Theory for C$^{*}$-algebras and I am stuck on one detail in exercise 8.17.

Let $A$ be a unital C$^{*}$-algebra. In this book, the stabilization $\mathcal{K}A$ of $A$ is defined to be the limit of the following inductive sequence:

$$
A\overset{\varphi_{1}}{\longrightarrow}M_{2}(A)\overset{\varphi_{2}}{\longrightarrow}M_{3}(A)\overset{\varphi_{3}}{\longrightarrow}\cdots\longrightarrow (\mathcal{K}A,\{\kappa_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}),
$$

where $\phi_{n}\colon M_{n}(A)\to M_{n+1}(A)$ is given by $\varphi_{n}(a)=\pmatrix{a & 0\\ 0 & 0}$, and the $\kappa_{n}\colon M_{n}(A)\to\mathcal{K}A$ are injective.

Let $\mathcal{U}_{n}(A):=\{u\in M_{n}(A):u\text{ is unitary}\}$ and $e_{n}=\kappa_{n}(1_{n})$, and define $\rho_{n}\colon\mathcal{U}_{n}(A)\to\mathcal{U}(\widetilde{\mathcal{K}A})$ by $\rho_{n}(u)=\kappa_{n}(u)+1-e_{n}$.

For a unitary of the form $v=(b,1)\in\widetilde{\mathcal{K}A}$, I was able to prove that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\|v-(e_{n}ve_{n}+(1-e_{n}))\|=0\qquad(*)
$$

However, the exercise then states to use $(*)$ and exercise 2.8 to prove the following:

> There is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and a $u\in \mathcal{U}_{n}(A)$ such that
>   $v\sim_{h}\rho_{n}(u)$.$\qquad(**)$

This is the part I am unable to figure out. I know that two given two unitaries $w_{1},w_{2}$, then $w_{1}\sim_{h} w_{2}$ if $\|w_{1}-w_{2}\|<2$, but I am really unsure how to piece this, $(*)$, and exercise 2.8 together to prove $(**)$.

Below, I have copied exercise 2.8 for reference:

[image]

As a final note, I should point out that the ultimate purpose of this problem is to prove that $\mathcal{U}(\widetilde{\mathcal{K}A})/\mathcal{U}_{0}(\widetilde{\mathcal{K}A})\cong\mathcal{U}_{\infty}(A)/\sim_{1}\cong K_{1}(A)$, which, assuming $(**)$, I was able to prove.

Comment: I am trying to solve this question now, and I am stuck on just the last bit: The $\rho_n$ will then clearly assemble to give a well-defined group homomorphism $\mathcal{U}_{\infty}/\sim_1 \to \mathcal{U}(\widetilde{\mathcal{K}A})/\mathcal{U}_0(\widetilde{\mathcal{K}A})$, which is a surjective by the hint in the problem. However, I am having trouble showing it is injective. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $e_n b e_n$ is in the image of $\varphi_n$ and that $e_nbe_n\to b$ (this is $(*)$ expressed in another way). Further since $1+b$ is unitary in $\widetilde{\mathcal {KA}}$ you have that $1+e_nbe_n$ converges to a unitary and as such
$$(1+e_nb e_n)^*(1+e_nbe_n) = 1 + e_n (b+b^*+ b^* e_nb )e_n$$
converges to $1$, ie $e_n(b+b^*+b^*e_nb)e_n\to 0$ and $\|e_n-(e_n+e_nbe_n)^*(e_n+e_nbe_n)\|\to 0$, the same with $e_n-(e_n+e_nbe_n)(e_n+e_nb e_n)^*$. Replace every $e_n$ by $1_n$ and apply the exercise in the picture to find an $n$ and a unitary $u$ in $M_n(\mathcal A)$ for which $\|u-(e_n+e_nbe_n)\|$ is arbitrarily small.

Then $\rho_n(u) = u+(1-e_n)$ is unitary in $\widetilde{\mathcal{KA}}$ and 
$$\|\rho_n(u) - (1+b)\| ≤ \|u-(e_n+e_nbe_n)\|+\|e_nbe_n-b\|.$$
Now both terms can be made arbitrarily small in particular $<2$, which by the criterium in the question implies $\rho_n(u) \sim_h (1,b)$.

Comment: I find myself a bit confused as I read this. For example, why should $e_n+\overline{b}$ be unitary in $M_n(A)$? By definition $e_n=\kappa_n(1_n)$, so belongs to the stabilisation of $A$. It seems to me that $1_n+\overline{b}$ is a unitary in that matrix algebra, and then taking $u=1_n+\overline{b}$ seems to give the desired unitary to finish the proof, so I find the final sentance confusing as well. Perhaps I am just overlooking something since this would mean exercise 2.8 as per the hint isnt used at all?

Comment: As you note $e_n$ is not in $M_m(A)$, writing that is abuse of notation and what should be written is $\phi_{m,n}(1_n)$ (or in the case $n=m$ just $1_n$). $1_n+\tilde b$ is the desired unitary. The last sentence may be confusing because I don't know what $v\sim_h \rho_n(u)$ means, so I just satisfied the condition described in the question (in the text after $(**)$ ). It may be that exercise 2.8 is used in deriving this condition or in deriving $(*)$ itself.

Comment: I think the answer may be false because $1_n+\tilde b$ is not unitary in $M_n(A)$, rather it should be "close" to a unitary where closeness increases with $n$. This motivates an explicit connection to exercise 2.8. I will think about and try to correct it when I have more time.

Comment: $1_n+\overline{b}$ being "close" to a unitary certainly sounds more likely, especially since what I had scribbled down before was wrong. . .

Comment: @user505379 I decided to redo the exercise, it looks correct now.